# Spring 4 With EMail not running

Tags: spring, email

**Configure pom.xml dependency are :**

================================================

```
<properties>

        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions>           
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version> -->

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Email -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</project>
```

=====================================================

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class Mail{

    @RequestMapping(value = "mail.html", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
    public ModelAndView mail(final ModelMap modelMap,final String userName, final String password,final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response, final String wp,ModelMap map,String nso) {  

        System.out.println("debug point read");

        MailThread mm = new MailThread();  // problem area

        mm.sendMail("text testing", "xyz@anyemail.xyz", "subject");
    return null;
    }
```

========================================================

// We define this class same package (This class working if its run with main method)

```
    private static final Session session = createSmtpSession();

    private static Session createSmtpSession() {

        final Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("mail.host","IP ADDRESS");

        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port","25");

        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");

        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol","MY PROTOCOL");

        return Session.getDefaultInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                        return new PasswordAuthentication("host email","password");

                    }
                });
    }

    public void sendMail(final String text, String toMail,final String subject) {

        Boolean mailSent = false;

        try {

                final Transport transport = session.getTransport();

                final MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

                message.setSubject(subject);

                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from"));

                message.setContent(text, "text/html");


                    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(toMail));

                    transport.connect();

                    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));

                }


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return mailSent;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MailThread mm = new MailThread();

        mm.sendMail("text testing", "xyz@anyemail.xyz", "subject");
    }
}
```

=========================================================================

**I got this problem when read `MailThread mm = new MailThread();`  this line**

```
Aug 17, 2015 3:17:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/agencyv1] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Address
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.superadmin.loginSAController.loginPage(loginSAController.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `javax.mail.Address` is not found. When you do a `Ctrl + Shft + T` in eclipse, can you find that class? Maybe maven clean/install is not successful. Also, why are you doing a `new MailThread();`? Shouldn't there be a bean defined in the configuration xml and used here?

Comment: I have already add dependency on pom.xml and its shows file and there is no issue no compile time.                                                                                                         If i deploy the war then its work fine. But when i run it from eclipse and start server it gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem come due to .jar not found even we define in pom. but actually it did not load. If you work with pom it works fine.                                                  you can add lib  1. activation-1.1.jar, 2.commons-logging-1.1.3, mail-1.4               in projectName\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\ folder.

Comment: or you can add a lib folder any where and define in pom.xml like                              <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
         <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.4</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/mail-1.4.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency>